# Replace json value by jsonpath

Tags: java, json

we have such a json string:

```
{
"key1": {
    "key2": {
        "key6": true
    },
    "key6": {
        "key3": [
            {
                "key4": "1",
                "key5": "1"
            },
            {
                "key4": "1",
                "key5": "1"
            }
        ]
    }

},
"from": 0
}
```

we want to use below code to replace latter key6's value:

```
DocumentContext dContext = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(objectString);
dContext.set("$.key6"+,"false"));
```

But as key6 has been shown in the jsonstring twice, we got the wrong value replaced. The above json structure is just one example, the json path for "key6" is quite different in different json. We couldn't write the exact jsonpath for this kind of replacement. 
How can we just replace the value of "key6" which has no child by java?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your only solution is to go to precise key, in your case, something like this:

```
dContext.set("$.key1.key2.key6"+,"false"));
```